# Image Sitemap with Zend_Navigation

Tags: image, zend-framework, sitemap

I generate a Sitemap using Zend_Navigation and i wanted to add images to this sitemap, now i got no Idea how to get this done, i use following (working) code to generate the sitemap

```
foreach($sitemapItems as $item)
    {
        $newSite = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri();
        $newSite->uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $item->getSpeakingUrl();
        $newSite->lastmod = $item->getUpdatedAt();
        $newSite->changefreq = 'weekly';

        $this->_navigation->addPage($newSite);
    }

    $this->view->navigation($this->_navigation);
    $this->view->navigation()->sitemap()->setFormatOutput(true);
```

The Output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        <url>
            <loc>http://test.dev/pictures/site-28.html</loc>
            <lastmod>2010-03-11T17:47:30+01:00</lastmod>
            <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
         </url>
         ....
```

I need the following Output inside the Url part

```
<image:image>
    <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
</image:image>
```

i tried to just set

```
$newSite->image = URI
```

but it didnt work also i tried to add custom attribute via

```
$newSite->__set('image', array('loc' => URI));
```

Does anyone know if what i want is even possible ? i cant find anything in the docs or web...

Thanks for your time,
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki so first what you need to do is extend Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri and add you're image var to it smth like below :

```
    class Mylib_NavPageUriImage extends Zend_Navigation_Page_Uri
{
    protected $_image = null;

    public function setImage($image)
    {
        if (null !== $image && !is_string($image)) {
            require_once 'Zend/Navigation/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Navigation_Exception(
                    'Invalid argument: $image must be a string or null');
        }

        $this->_image = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->_image;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return array_merge(
            parent::toArray(),
            array(
                'image' => $this->getImage()
            ));
    }
}
```

Add this class to library/Mylib/NavPageUriImage.php.

To make it usable you need to register the namespace ( i like to register my namespaces at bootstrap but it can be done from app.ini too ) so in you're bootstrap class add the following :

```
function _initNamespace()
    {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace('Mylib_');
    }
```

Then in you're controller you can now use :

```
$newSite = new Mylib_NavPageUriImage();
$newSite->uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $item->getSpeakingUrl();
$newSite->lastmod = $item->getUpdatedAt();
$newSite->changefreq = 'weekly';
$newSite->image = 'some image';
```

THE FOLLOWING IS NOT RECOMENDED , YOU NEED TO EXTEND YOU'RE OWN NAVIGATION HELPER AND USE THAT ( i just don't have the time to play with it now ) ALLSO ADD YOU'RE OWN imageValidator

And then in library/zend/view/helper/navigation/sitemap.php add the following lines ( under the add priority element if statement , mine ends at 443 so i added this at 444 ) :

```
// add 'image' element if a valid image is set in page
if (isset($page->image)) {
    $image = $page->image;
        $imgDom = $dom->createElementNS(self::SITEMAP_NS, 'image:image');
        $imgDom->appendChild($dom->createElementNS(self::SITEMAP_NS, 'image:loc', $image));
    $urlNode->appendChild($imgDom);
}
```

---